# Tomcat 7 on Linux Cannot Locate Java Class in Grails 3 War File

Tags: java, tomcat, grails

I have a **grails 3** project, with java source code in the src/main/groovy/ folder (as specified [here](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html) ).

The code works well in IntelliJ IDE and when deployed on Mac OS X El Capitan with a Tomcat 7 Server (tested with 7.0.73, 7.0.70, and 7.0.33, installed as specified [here](https://wolfpaulus.com/journal/mac/tomcat7/) )

**Server Details (Where the error happens)**

However on a Red Hat Linux Server the tomcat version command reports the following (though the startup default page lists version 7.0.33),

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Server built:   Aug 5 2016 19:24:52 UTC
Server number:  7.0.70.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-642.6.2.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_111-b14
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

the war file runs when put in the web app directory, but stalls on any page that uses a the java class in src/main/groovy with the following error (in the catalina.out log file),

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/url/] due to exception [Could not initialize class package_name.class_name]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class package_name.class_name
```

and occasionally gives this error (though seemed to stop after setting up LD_LIBRARY_PATH on Linux),

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter - Forwarding to error page from request [/url] due to exception [no opencv_java310 in java.library.path]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
```

**Several things that do work,**

- The code builds successfully to a war file
- When navigating to webapps/war_name/WEB-INF/classes/package_name/ the class file is there, AND can be run using (from the classes/ folder not package_name/) java package_name.class_name.
- A test program that uses opencv runs successfully, on the server, so it seems the native libraries are correctly installed.
- The same war file works on Mac OS El Capitan with Tomcat versions 7.0.70, 7.0.73, 7.0.33, however it uses the bin shell scripts and not a service.

Answer (score 0):

This is because tomcat does NOT respect the LD_LIBRARY_PATH setting on the Linux machine. So any test program run with java ... (including running java tomcat_dir/webapps/war_name/classes/File.class ) will work, but it still will break under tomcat and complain about failure to import the class. The fix for this is to ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH (or don't use Tomcat!, I wish), and symlink or copy the so file to one of the java.library.path paths.